# Android won't use my long (wide aspect ratio) drawable images on long devices

Tags: android, android-drawable, screen-orientation, android-image

I have a multi-page app that is working great except for image loading. Each page has a fullscreen image. I have 5 drawable folders -- the default one without any page images in it and then these four:

- `drawable-long`
- `drawable-notlong`
- `drawable-long-xhdpi`
- `drawable-notlong-xhdpi`

My app is set to only landscape. The image files in `notlong` are 4x3 aspect ratio. In `long` they are 16x9 aspect ratio.

On the Nexus 7 and 5, both devices report a screen type of long yet use the 4x3 images from `drawnble-notlong-xhdpi`. How can I get them to use the `long` images?

If I remove the two `notlong` folders, on app startup I get a `NotFoundException` on the image resource (which crashes the app).

I did add the equivalent `layout` views but still the 4x3 image is being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [Android resource notlong / long identifiers not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752381/android-resource-notlong-long-identifiers-not-working) as it turns out there was a bug -- my code telling me if the screen was long or not was wrong. For a Nexus 7, 1920/1200 = 1.6 which is less than the 1.667 ratio that triggers the long view as mentioned in the linked to Q&A. So Android is working correctly however the normal aspect ratio can be quite a ways from 4x3 so one has to take that into account.