# Splash Screen Background for 18:9 Aspect Ratio (Samsung Galaxy S8)

Tags: android

I have implemented a splash screen in android with a full image background using a drawable resource. This displays correctly on traditional screen aspect ratios. When I now run it in Samsung Galaxy S8 which has an aspect ratio of 18:9, the background image get's stretched vertically.

I shy away from using a layout as my splash screen as there will be a delay for the image to show up.

One thing I can think of is if we have a specific image sized for 18:9 but then how can I make it so that android will pick that specific image based on certain aspect ratio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use screen aspect qualifier and make a different layout for long screen devices and Android will detect it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

Comment: according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752381/android-resource-notlong-long-identifiers-not-working
the `long` resource qualifier applies for 16:9 screens as well - so cannot distinguish between 16:9 and 18:9

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect answer but it works in situation where you don't care about little bit cropping of image, add

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

in imageview tag of splash xml.