# Android Splash Screen with 18:9 aspect ratio support

Tags: java, android, kotlin, splash-screen

I'm having trouble with the splash screen of the App i'm developing. I've set the 6 images with the classic resolutions (portrait only):

- LDPI: 200 x 320 pixels
- MDPI: 320 x 480 pixels
- HDPI: 480 x 720 pixels
- XHDPI: 640 x 960 pixels
- XXHDPI: 960 x 1440 pixels
- XXXHDPI: 1280 x 1920 pixels

This has been working fine so far since new devices came out with 18:9 aspect ratios.

If I install the app on a large screen, the splash looks stretched. I cannot use a nine patch image because the splash screen is an image with multiple elements, it's not a logo in a static background.

My question is if it's possible to create an extra XXXXHDPI-large or something similar with new splash screens in 18:9 resolutions. This would keep compatibility with older devices while new devices show the splash correctly.

I've also tried adding new ratio resource file and works fine, but It also detects some 16:9 resolutions as "large" and then the 18:9 splash I've created is also shown on some 16:9 devices. I've followed steps from the following link:

[Splash Screen Background for 18:9 Aspect Ratio (Samsung Galaxy S8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47493606/splash-screen-background-for-189-aspect-ratio-samsung-galaxy-s8)

What should I do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you add a screenshot? you can always use a frame layout with an image view inside it, and center it.